# Unable to reroute on page symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to create a new page in symfony,

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class LuckyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/luckynumber")
     */
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = mt_rand(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

Routing is set up like this

```
app:
resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
type:     annotation
```

And I am trying to access it on this url `https://proj/proj/web/luckynumber`. It just returns `404` Error.. My project is in `https://proj/proj` folder.

Comment: From you console command terminal what returns with:  `php app/console debug:router`? (for symfony3 is: `php bin/console debug:router`). Do you see that route?

Comment: Yes, there is a row with `name:app_lucky_number Path:/luckynumber`

Comment: Well. Now you can clear the app cache manually (deleting the env cache folder) or with: `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev` and try to enter the correct url. If you are working in local, it should be: yourdomain.ltd/app_dev.php/luckynumber

Comment: PS: each time you add a translation key, add a route, ... clear the cache before post here! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The url should be https://proj/proj/luckynumber

You can also try https://proj/proj/app_dev.php/luckynumber to be sure it's not a cache problem